# Unable to run spark on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: docker, pyspark, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I get this error:

```
[FATAL tini (9)] exec /usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark failed: No such file or directory
```

While running the following command in terminal:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 4040:4040 \
jupyter/pyspark-notebook \
/usr/local/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to manually log into your docker container with shell and check the paths. To do that, you would:

```
docker run -it --rm jupyter/pyspark-notebook sh
```

and then use `ls` to loop through directory tree.

Actually, **current version** of `jupyter/pyspark-notebook`, used in your docker, uses `spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7` (notice version mismatch), so your answer is:

Use

```
docker run -it --rm -p 4040:4040 jupyter/pyspark-notebook /usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark
```

Comment: thank you for the answer however still not working. It is not my docker container I am trying to use. Thus after following your feedback, I got a message to enter the credentials of the owner of the image on the server for which I do not have access.